# Shouldn't Z(compressibility factor) be < 1 for all real gases?

Tags: kinetic-theory, gas

So compressibility factor(z) is defined as $$Z = \frac{V_{real}}{V_{ideal}}$$ where $ V_{real}$ is volume occupied by real gas and $V_{ideal}$ is volume occupied by ideal gas at same conditions but by van der Waals equation, volume of real gas is $V_{real} = V_{ideal} - nb$ where b is a positive constant therefore my question is how Z>1 is possible as $V_{real}$ is always less than $V_{ideal}$ by van der Waals equation.Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Because not all gases are either ideal or van der Waals. The interactions in the gas phase at various temperatures and densities can be quite complex.

Comment: At high pressures (above the critical pressure), z can be greater than 1.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility_factor#/media/File:Compressibility_Factor_of_Air_75-200_K.png

Comment: David, that's exactly why I asked the question because I am confused how can z be greater than 1